# Created Docker Container process not getting listed

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

Created **Docker** container process is not showing using command `docker ps --all`

I have created only one **Dockerfile** in a directory, and which is a single available file inside the directory.

the **Dockerfile** contains following lines:

```
# Use an existing docker image as a base
FROM alpine

# Download and install a dependency
RUN apk add --update redis

# Tell the image what to do when it starts
# as a container
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

and after saving the file with name "Dockerfile" and without any extension, I am simply executing the command to build using `docker build .`

and the logs are as follows:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
 ---> a24bb4013296
Step 2/3 : RUN apk add --update redis
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 218559ae3e9b
Step 3/3 : CMD ["redis-server"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fc607b62e266
Successfully built fc607b62e266
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

so, as above you can see the container image process is getting built successfully, but still the container not getting displayed using `docker ps --all` command.

Well I am using Windows 10 x64 OS & with assurance that no antivirus or firewall is blocker this docker. Am I missing something or making any mistake here?

Comment: Well `docker run busybox echo hello-world` is showing in `docker ps --all` containers process reference list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker ps` works like the unix command `ps`.  It doesn't show all the docker images that *could* be run.  It only shows the docker containers that *are* running (or with `-a`, *have been* run).

You've built a docker image but you haven't yet run it with `docker run`.

Try `docker run --rm -it fc607b62e266` and if you have everything et up right, it should start up your redis server.  (`--rm` removes the container when it stops running, generally a good practice unless you want it to persist).

You'll see your new image - not *container* because it hasn't been instantiated yet - in the output of `docker images`.  Add a `-t` flag to give a tag to your `docker build`  command and you'll see it under that name, otherwise, you can always use the image ref.

A container will only run while it's underlying "root process" is running.     When running a service like `redis-server`, this means the container will run until signaled (docker service restart, system restrart, or `docker kill`).

While it *is* running, more processes can be executed within the container with `docker exec`.  Each of these is a separate process, but all will be terminated when the "root process" ends.  The converse, of course, is not true - ending the `exec`ed process doesn't affect the "root process".

Comment: earlier I were using the command `docker exec -it <container_build_id> sh` and it were executing fine, but sudden it were not working, because the container were not available, could you tell this situation?

Comment: find it, `Successfully built fc607b62e266` is an image reference, not a container id, and using the command `docker run --rm -it fc607b62e266` the container process will start and so the container detail will get populated in `docker ps --all` containers status logs list.

Comment: I added some exec vs run info that can hopefully help you